# Pytest asserting fixture after teardown

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a test that makes a thing, validates it, deletes the thing and confirms it was deleted.

```py
def test_thing():
    thing = Thing()  # Simplified, it actually takes many lines to make a thing

    assert thing.exists

    thing.delete()  # Simplified, it also takes a few lines to delete it

    assert thing.deleted
```

Next I want to make many more tests that all use the thing, so it's a natural next step to move the thing creation/deletion into a fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture
def thing():
    thing = Thing()  # Simplified, it actually takes many lines to make a thing
    yield thing
    thing.delete()  # Simplified, it also takes a few lines to delete it

def test_thing(thing):
    assert thing.exists

def test_thing_again(thing):
    # Do more stuff with thing

...
```

But now I've lost my `assert thing.deleted`.

I feel like I have a few options here, but none are satisfying.

1. I could assert in the fixture but AFAIK it's bad practice to put assertions in the fixture because if it fails it will result in an `ERROR` instead of a `FAIL`.
2. I could keep my original test and also create the fixture, but this would result in a lot of duplicated code for creating/deleting the thing.
3. I can't call the fixture directly because I get a `Fixture called directly` exception so I could move the thing creation out into a generator that is used by both the fixture and the test. This feels clunky though and what happens if my `thing` fixture needs to use another fixture?

What is my best option here? Is there something I haven't thought of?

Comment: To clarify, is this just a case of wanting `thing` to not be deleted twice in a `test_delete_thing` (once in the test and once in teardown)?

Comment: Yeah, I want to avoid deleting twice. First because the fixture would likely fail if it has already been deleted, and second because that would be a duplication of the deletion code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test that a "thing" is deleted, make a fixture without teardown, delete it in the test, then assert if it is deleted.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def thing_create():
    # Perform all the creation steps
    thing = Thing()
    ...

    yield thing


def thing_delete(thing):
    # Perform all the deletion steps
    ...
    thing.delete()  


@pytest.fixture
def thing_all(thing_create):
    yield thing_create
    thing_delete(thing_create)


def test_thing(thing_all):
    assert thing_all.exists


def test_thing_again(thing_create):
    thing_delete(thing_create)
    assert thing_create.deleted
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about making the fixture in two halves. This is a good idea. The `thing_create.delete()` could also be in a function that is used in both places to reduce the duplication too.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with this idea :)

Comment: Wow, I just saw your edit @JacobTomlinson, never do a function to wrap a single simple function call.

Comment: Well of course, but in reality it is way more than a simple function call. I had just simplified for SO, hence the "Simplified" comment.

Comment: I understand, but this can give other user bad practices. Nothing prevent you doing it in your code where the deletion is more complexe, but on this example, keep it simple.

Comment: This example no longer satisfies the question though. The create code and delete code should only happen in one place. Let me suggest one more edit.

Comment: I'd suggest viewing [safe fixture structure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#safe-fixture-structure) in the pytest docs to see how to extend Dorian's method to more complex applications

Comment: @JacobTomlinson ok but add comment in the function to make it clear that the delete process is more complex and boilerplate than the `.delete` call :)

Comment: @DorianTurba thanks, I tried to make it clear. Are you happy with that?

Comment: @JacobTomlinson I'm sorry, i didn't noticed the inline comments on method call. Still, the  new version is better, in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

How about using the fixture where appropriate (to reduce duplication) but not where your logic only exists once.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def thing():
    thing = Thing()  # Simplified, it actually takes many lines to make a thing
    yield thing
    thing.delete()  # Simplified, it also takes a few lines to delete it

def test_thing(thing):
    assert thing.exists

def test_thing_does_a_thing(thing):
    expected = "expected"
    assert thing.do_thing() == expected

def test_thing_deletes():
    # just don't use the fixture here
    thing = Thing()
    thing.delete()
    assert thing.deleted
```

Comment: Yeah this is basically option 2, just duplicate the code. My actual fixture is quite large though, so I wanted to avoid the duplication if possible.

Comment: That makes sense. I'd suggest making one fixture extend another by adding deletion logic but I see Dorian's answer already suggests that

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to have a single fixture that yields a context manager, so the test can be in full control of invoking it.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def gen_thing():

    @contextmanager
    def cm():
        thing = Thing()  # Simplified, it actually takes many lines to make a thing
        try:
            yield thing
        finally:
            thing.delete()  # Simplified, it also takes a few lines to delete it

    yield cm


def test_thing(gen_thing):
    with gen_thing() as thing:
        assert thing.exists
    assert thing.deleted


def test_thing_again(gen_thing):
    with gen_thing() as thing:
        # Do more stuff with thing
```

Creating the context manager as a closure means it would have the same scope as the fixture too.

Comment: Good idea, but can be considered boilerplate code

Comment: Yeah totally agree. It is a compromise that increases complexity in exchange for flexibility. Its not clear if that compromise is worth it.